# Python: How do I convert a string inside a list to a json inside a list whilst retaining the double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

This is for python 3.x, I'm struggling to convert the following

```
['{"from": "USD", "to": "EUR"}']
```

to

```
[{"from": "USD", "to": "EUR"}]
```

I have tried using ast.literal_eval(s) but that returns my json in single quotes, I've been trying different combinations for well over an hour to no avail, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `json.loads`. Why do you care for the double quotes?

Comment: @DeepSpace The server written up in a different language needs the json to be in double quotes unfortunately.

Comment: What kind of server is that? Most servers should be able to handle that. The single/double quotes is a Python thing. If you are getting any errors you should edit your question and post them.

Comment: JSON syntax is not Python syntax. JSON requires double quotes for its strings.

Comment: Your title says you want to convert to JSON but then your question shows that you don't. Which is it?

Comment: @Stefan Pochman My bad, I want to convert the string inside the list to a json inside a list. Is saying json the wrong terminology? Should I be calling it a dictionary instead?

Comment: If you turn it into that, you have a _Python object in memory_. It doesn't use any particular kind of quotes until you print it. What do you want to send to the server exactly?

Comment: @user4659009 Well JSON is a string. A string in a certain format, representing data. Yes, your "to" result is just a dictionary. And doesn't contain any quotes, neither double nor single. The quotes you see when you **print** the dictionary are not any part of its actual value.

Comment: @user4659009: the first is a Python list that has a JSON string inside it. The second is a Python list that has a Python dictionary inside it.

Comment: I'm getting the error message `WebResponse(400, The request content was malformed: expected false got f (line 1, column 1))` which I'm told means I'm using single quotes when sending it up to the server, hence why I'm trying to create a python list with a python dictionary inside it to see if that makes a difference when I hit the server.

Comment: @user4659009: you can't send Python objects over a network to a server. You can only send _strings_ over a network. Use `json.dumps()` to go from a Python object to a string containing the object encoded as JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json.loads` and `json.dumps`. It will take care of it for you:

```
import json

a = ['{"from": "USD", "to": "EUR"}']
obj = json.loads(a[0])
print(obj, type(obj))
>> {'to': 'EUR', 'from': 'USD'} <class 'dict'>

print(json.dumps(obj), type(json.dumps(obj)))
>> {"to": "EUR", "from": "USD"} <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> c=['{"from": "USD", "to": "EUR"}']
>>> c[0]
'{"from": "USD", "to": "EUR"}'
>>> eval( c[0])
{'to': 'EUR', 'from': 'USD'}
>>> p=eval(c[0])
>>> print p
{'to': 'EUR', 'from': 'USD'}
>>> type(p)
<type 'dict'>
```

Comment: Using eval should be always avoided as it's a big security hole.